# Error with the Canvas Gradient

Tags: javascript, canvas, requestanimationframe

Hello I have a little problem with the HTML Canvas. For a project for the university we have to create many small circles with a gradient. However, the function works from a certain number an error:

> "failed to execute 'createradialgradient' on
>   'canvasrenderingcontext2d': the provided double value is non-finite."

It actually works so far and after hours of searching I am sure that it is a performance problem. Can it be that I have a mistake here?

```js
draw() : void {
    this.ctx.clearRect(0,0,this.canvasWidth,this.canvasHeight);
    this.sequenceArray.forEach(sequenceArray => {
        sequenceArray.updateSound();
    });
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {this.draw()});
}
```

```js
let gradient = this.ctx.createRadialGradient(this.xPos,this.yPos,0,this.xPos,this.yPos,this.radius);
        gradient.addColorStop(0.8, 'rgba(255,255,255,0)');
        gradient.addColorStop(1,'rgba(255,255,255,0.2)');
        this.ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
        this.ctx.beginPath();
        this.ctx.globalAlpha = this.opacity;
        this.ctx.arc(this.xPos,this.yPos,this.radius,0,Math.PI*2,true);
        this.ctx.fill();
```

Basically everything works wonderfully only if there are too many elements coming the mistake.

Comment: The problem must come from either `this.xPos`, `this.yPos` or `this.radius` but you don't show where these properties come from nor how they are updated. Log these, find the ones that are not finite, find which entity they belong to, find why they are non finite, have a drink, job done.

Comment: hmm ok thx i will try this.